# How does C# Implementation of Flagged Enum work and how can Scala solve the same issue?

Tags: c#, scala, enums

I am trying to understand how Flagged Enums work in C# and how I can implement similar functionality in Scala.

I was surprised that Enum, which is a special data type that enables a variable to be a set of **predefined** constants can be actually a combination of enums and compile in C# as follows:

```cs
[Flags]
enum Permissions
{
  None = 0,
  Read = 1,
  Write = 2,
  Execute = 4
}
// ...

Permissions x = Permissions.Read | Permissions.Write;  # How | Is Implemented???
```

However, when attempting to create an enum or an ADT in Scala, I could not implement the `|` operator since I was unable to construct new Permissions out of this and other: Permissions.

Currently, I am aware of libraries such as Enumeration and Enumeratum, as well as ADTs and Scala 3, but I have not found a way to create Flagged Enums using these methods.

Specifically, I would like to know how the `|` operator works with Enums in C# and how this can be achieved in Scala.

Can someone explain the implementation of Flagged Enums in C# and provide some guidance on how to achieve similar functionality in Scala?

*Update*:
https://gist.github.com/ZviMints/e0edaabb1df169233cdf746e26fb1257

Comment: Enums are ints and `|` is binary or

Comment: Declare a type alias for `Int` and declare some named integer constants. C# enums are just that, but with a tiny bit more type safety.

Comment: Enums does not have `|` in Scala, but it can be retrieved by the underlying value, but the return type is the same underlying value. 

Regarding the Declaration of type alias, its a good idea but lets say I have several enums, I cannot distinguish between them since they of the same type `Int` and not different types like I want in typed language

Comment: Well then make a wrapper around `Int` then. It's not that safe in C# either. You can cast any enum to any other enum by casting it to an integer type first.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, but they still can be overloaded in the same class.
I'm trying to understand how the `|` operator is implemented in `C#`, ```how def | (other: Enum): Enum``` can return Enum type? its probably should use some `Set` underlying in that what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: C# enums are just thin wrappers around integer types. `|` is just bitwise OR on the wrapped integer values. Why do you think that `|` *can't* return an enum type? I'll say this again - enum types in C# are just thin wrappers around integer types. There is nothing stopping you from wrapping a `3`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Scala enums, which as far as I know can only have a fixed number of instances. C# enums are just thin wrappers around integer types. There is nothing preventing anyone from creating a `Permissions` wrapping the value 12334567 (not that this makes sense):

```cs
var p = (Permissions)1234567;
```

`|` is just bitwise OR on the wrapped integer values. The specification specifies this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12133-enumeration-logical-operators):

> Every enumeration type E implicitly provides the following predefined
> logical operators:
>
> ```
> E operator &(E x, E y);
> E operator |(E x, E y);
> E operator ^(E x, E y);
> ```
>
> The result of evaluating x «op» y, where x and y are expressions of an
> enumeration type E with an underlying type U, and «op» is one of the
> logical operators, is exactly the same as evaluating (E)((U)x «op»
> (U)y). In other words, the enumeration type logical operators simply
> perform the logical operation on the underlying type of the two
> operands.

The "underlying type" here is an integer type. By default, it is `int`.

You can easily implement something similar in Scala, by writing a wrapper around `Int`. Add an operator overload for `|`, and some named constants in the companion object.

```scala
// this is just the general idea - excuse me if this is not idiomatic
// I'm not very familiar with Scala
final class Permissions private(private val value: Int) {
  def |(other: Permissions) = new Permissions(value | other.value)
  def hasFlag(flag: Permissions) = (value & flag.value) > 0
}
object Permissions {
  val None = new Permissions(0)
  val Read = new Permissions(1)
  val Write = new Permissions(2)
  val Execute = new Permissions(4)
}

// this works!
val permission = Permissions.Read | Permissions.Write
println(permission.hasFlag(Permissions.Read)) // true
println(permission.hasFlag(Permissions.Write)) // true
println(permission.hasFlag(Permissions.Execute)) // false
```

C# enums with `[Flags]` also have a custom implementation of `ToString`, which outputs all the flags the value has. You can write a similar `toString` implementation in Scala.

Comment: Nice! I managed to understand now how its works - I created a gist with examples `https://gist.github.com/ZviMints/e0edaabb1df169233cdf746e26fb1257`

Comment: Is it possible to create a generic implementation for FlaggedEnum? since the `def |` need to be duplicate along all of our enums, instead create one implementation.
Note that the usage should return the subtype, for e.g `val featureStatus: SubtypeEnum = SubtypeEnum.A | SubtypeEnum.B`

Comment: @ZviMints Sorry, I don't know enough Scala to answer that. Perhaps you can ask in the comments of the duplicate target, or post a new question?

Comment: Asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76254022/how-can-i-implement-a-abstract-flagged-enum-with-support-for-bitwise-operations, thanks!