# How can I implement a abstract flagged enum with support for bitwise operations?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm trying to create a generic implementation of `Flagged` enum which supports bitwise operations such as `|`, `&`, `hasFlag`, etc.

This is a followup question after the following 2 topics:

- [How does C# Implementation of Flagged Enum work and how can Scala solve the same issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76207142/how-does-c-sharp-implementation-of-flagged-enum-work-and-how-can-scala-solve-the)
- [Enum with Parameters to Scala 3 Causes Serialization Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76228015/enum-with-parameters-to-scala-3-causes-serialization-errors)

I tried to do something as follows:

```scala
class FlaggedEnum(val value: Long) {
  def | (other: FlaggedEnum): FlaggedEnum = new FlaggedEnum(value | other.value)
}

sealed case class Permissions(override val value: Long) extends FlaggedEnum(value)
object Permissions:
  object Write extends Permissions(1 << 0)
  object Read  extends Permissions(1 << 1)



@main def main(): Unit =
  val permissions: Permissions = Permissions.Write | Permissions.Read
  println(permissions)
```

The code is not compiling, because `Permissions.Write | Permissions.Read` returns `FlaggedEnum` and not `Permissions` which I want to remain, like in `C#` implementation and other languages.

Also Its impossible to create FlaggedEnum as `abstract` class because of the return type of `|` operation.

How can I create a abstract Flagged Enum implementation in Scala so I will not duplicate the `|`, `&`, etc implementation across all my enums in the application?

Comment: Are the any other requirements? At a glance it looks like use case for F-bound polymorphism or a type class.

Comment: The requirement is to create an abstract implementation with `|`, `&` and `hasFlag` which returns the subtype instance and the following should compile:
```val permissions: Permissions = Permissions.Write | Permissions.Read
```

Comment: Followup of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlVVhLvN71Y also

Comment: If you want an enum from Scala 3 then F-bound polymorphism should do.

Comment: Not sure how its can work on Scala 2, I'm looking solution for Scala 2 but out of curiosity an implemented solution for Scala 3 can be great also!

Comment: Didn't find any implemented solution for Flagged enum still on Scala

Comment: @ZviMints as Mateusz suggested, you may use either **F-Bound** or **Typelcass** polymorphism, check this FAQ: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type

Comment: In the following example: http://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html, I see that the `renamed` return `A` type indeed but its not implemented, I want to avoid duplication - Is it possible to get a simple example in new response please? thanks in advance!

Comment: Its means that I can define a trait with operations and then implement it by my own, but i do not want to implement it again and again, its will always `this.value | other.value` on `|` or bitwse.

Comment: I doubt that what you are trying to do is actually useful. Note, that the only reason for `Permissions` to be a different class from `FlaggedEnum` is for the former to have limited set of values (1, 2, 3) ... But if `|` is implemented in a generic way as you are trying to do, there would be nothing preventing you from creating a "permission" like `Read | FlaggedEnum(128)`, which is meaningless. And if you don't mind that being possible, then you problem is easily solved with `type Permission = FlaggedEnum` 

Comment: `Read | FlaggedEnum(128)` should not be possible, but `Read | Write` does, this probably can be achieved via `def | (other: A): A`.
My app has several Features Enum, for e.g `GeoFeatureStatus` , `BrandsafetyFeatureStatus`,  `FraudFeatureStatus`, etc... all of them is representing a features that the profile bough, but in the end they all need to have `|` operation because I want to store all the services he bough in one field which is not array.

Comment: I would like to implement it like flagged enum in `C#` which is very easy (https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
abstract class FlaggedEnum[T <: FlaggedEnum[T]](val value: Long)  {
   def copy(v: Long): T
   def |(other: T): T = copy(value | other.value)
}

case class Permissions(override val value: Long) extends FlaggedEnum[Permissions](value)
```

Comment: Thats great, can you add also the `Write` and `Read` case objects? its seems to have issues with extending Permissions with `case` to `case` and otherwise i need to implement `copy` with regular class

Comment: What's the problem with `val Write = Permissions(1)`?

Comment: Or use `object` same way you had in the question. That [works](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/hQW2lijYThme2UzYsby2eg) too ...

Comment: I liked that! the only issue I have is`withName`, checkout: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QisfrUe1QBiqcacyw2AiLA
Any ideas how to overcome it? you need to add `libraryDependencies += "com.beachape" %% "enumeratum" % "1.7.2"`

Comment: Plus its not working for me on Scala 2, its says ```Missing implementation for member of class FlaggedEnum:
  def copy(value: Long): BrandSafetyFeatureStatus = ??? // implements `def copy(value: Long): T```

Comment: Yeah, scala 2 doesn't let generated copy override the abstract member :/ 
Re. `withName` thing: I am not very familiar with `enumeratum` but I think it wants `Exclusion.toString` to return "Exclusion" (so, you'd have to define it explicitly, since if can't be a case object). 

Comment: [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ghqHo2X3QCWbuKLNvuoLrw) works in scala 2

Comment: `override def toString: String = getClass.getSimpleName.stripSuffix("$")`

Comment: Sure, that works ^^^ ... except, it'll mess up `BrandSafetyFeatureStatus(93)` ... which, I guess, you should not be able to have in the first place ... but you _can_ as I pointed out in my comment on the question . And then `Inclusion | Exclusion` would also end up just `BrandSafetyFeatureStatus`

Comment: Got it, is it possible to print the value if its `93` for example and if its a regular so print the String for example `Inclusion`? - Thanks!, I cannot pattern match for specific String since `T` type can be different

Comment: `Option(getClass.getSimpleName).filter(_.endsWith("$")).fold(super.toString){ _.stripSuffix("$") }` ?

Answer (score 3):

There are several options (if just having these methods is only requirement).

Option 1.: F-bound polymorphism

```
abstract class FlaggedEnum[T <: FlaggedEnum](val value: Long) {
  protected def wrapLong(l: Long): T

  final def & (other: T): T = wrapLong(value & other.value)
  final def | (other: T): T = wrapLong(value | other.value)

  // assuming sane equals generated by implementation of case class/object
  final def hasFlag(other: T): Boolean = (this & other) == other
}

// Scala 3
enum Permissions(value: Long) extends FlaggedEnum[Permissions](value):
  case Write extends Permissions(1 << 0)
  case Read  extends Permissions(1 << 1)
  case Computed(computed: Long) extends Permissions(computed)

  override protected def wrapLong(l: Long): Permissions = Computed(l)
```

Version for Scala 2 would we very similar, just with more boilerplate:

```
// Scala 2
sealed abstract class Permissions(value: Long) extends FlaggedEnum[Permissions](value) {
  
  override protected def wrapLong(l: Long): Permissions = Computed(l)
}
object Permissions {
  case object Write extends Permissions(1 << 0)
  case object Read  extends Permissions(1 << 1)
  final case class Computed(computed: Long) extends Permissions(computed)
}
```

(to be honest this being `enum` is `sealed trait` is completely unnecessary).

Option 2: type class and extension methods

```
// Scala 3
trait BitBasedPermissions[Permission]:
  
  def wrap(value: Long): Permission

  extension (permission: Permission)
    def value: Long
    final def & (other: Permission): Permission =
      wrap(permission.value & other.value)
    final def | (other: Permission): Permission =
      wrap(permission.value | other.value)
    // assuming sane equals generated by implementation of case class/object
    final def hasFlag(other: T): Boolean = (permission & other) == other

enum Permissions(inner: Long):
  case Write extends Permissions(1 << 0)
  case Read  extends Permissions(1 << 1)
  case Computed(computed: Long) extends Permissions(computed)

  given BitBasedPermissions[Permission] with
    
    def wrap(value: Long): Permission = Computed(value)

    extension (permission: Permissions)
      def value: Long = permission.inner
```

or, with significantly more boilerplate in Scala 2:

```
trait BitBasedPermissions[Permission] {

  def wrap(value: Long): Permission

  def value(permission: Permission): Long
}

// implicit class cannot be a top-level object, you'd have to put it into package object,
// or use class + implicit def and then import implicit manually 
implicit class BitBasedPermissionsOps[Permission](private val permission: Permission) {
  
  final def value(implicit P: BitBasedPermissions[Permission]): Long =
    P.value(permission)
  final def & (other: Permission)(implicit P: BitBasedPermissions[Permission]): Permission =
    P.wrap(permission.value & other.value)
  final def | (other: Permission)(implicit P: BitBasedPermissions[Permission]): Permission =
    P.wrap(permission.value | other.value)
  // assuming sane equals generated by implementation of case class/object
  final def hasFlag(other: T)(implicit P: BitBasedPermissions[Permission]): Boolean =
    (permission & other) == other
}

sealed abstract class Permissions(inner: Long)
object Permissions {
  case object Write extends Permissions(1 << 0)
  case object Read  extends Permissions(1 << 1)
  final case class Computed(computed: Long) extends Permissions(computed)

  implicit val bitBasedPermissions: BitBasedPermissions[Permission] =
    new BitBasedPermissions[Permission] {

      def wrap(value: Long): Permission = Computed(value)

      def value(permission: Permissions): Long = permission.inner
    }
}
```

However, TBH, I see hardly any reason to use an enum for this, you might as well just do:

```
final case class Permissions(value: Long)
object Permissions {
  val Write = Permissions(1 << 0)
  val Read  = Permissions(1 << 1)
}
```

since you are:

- not using pattern-matching and exhaustive checking
- combining arbitrarily many flags together
- probably needing something like empty flag
- not comparing permissions by comparing references to their objects but more likely delegating to some `hasFlag` to see if one set of permissions is a subset of another set of permissions

This `case class` could use F-bound polymorphism or type class just like examples with `enum`.

If you need to limit the possible flags (so that nobody would create an arbitrary `Permissions(420)` you can always do

```
final class Permissions private (inner: Long) extends FlaggedEnum[Permissions](inner) {
  override protected def wrapLong(l: Long): Permissions = new Permissions(l)
}
object Permissions {
  val Empty = new Permissions(0)
  val Write = new Permissions(1 << 0)
  val Read  = new Permissions(1 << 1)
}
```

EDIT:

After consideration I believe that what actually worked would be:

```
// type class if one want to implement it in whatever way they need it
trait Flag[F]:
  def values: List[F]
  extension (flag: F)
    def index: Int
    def value: Long = 1L << index
object Flag:
  // mixin which generates the instance automatically
  trait Companion[F <: scala.reflect.Enum]:
    companion =>
    // should be generated automatically for enum with parameterless cases only
    def values: Array[F]

    given Flag[F] with
      def values: List[F] = companion.values.toList
      extension (flag: F) def index: Int = flag.ordinal

// lightweight bag of flags
type Flags[F] = Flags.Impl[F]
object Flags:

  opaque type Impl[F] = Long
  object Impl:
    extension [F](impl: Impl[F]) def unwrap: Long = impl
    def wrap[F](long: Long): Impl[F] = long

  def empty[F]: Flags[F] = 0L

  def apply[F: Flag](flags: F*): Flags[F] =
    flags.foldLeft(0L) { (flags, flag) => flags | flag.value }

  def unapplySeq[F: Flag](flags: Flags[F]): Seq[F] =
    summon[Flag[F]].values.filter { flag =>
      (flags & (1L << flag.index)) != 0L
    }

  extension [F](flags: Flags[F])
    def &(other: Flags[F]): Flags[F] = Impl.wrap(flags.unwrap & other.unwrap)
    def |(other: Flags[F]): Flags[F] = Impl.wrap(flags.unwrap | other.unwrap)

    def hasFlags(other: Flags[F]): Boolean = (flags & other) == other

    def showFlags(using Flag[F]): String =
       unapplySeq(flags).mkString("Flags(", ", ", ")")
```

```
enum PermissionFlag:
  case Read
  case Write

object PermissionFlag extends Flag.Companion[PermissionFlag]

val flags = Flags(PermissionFlag.Read, PermissionFlag.Write)
println(flags.showFlags)
flags match {
  // needs to appear in order they are defined
  case Flags(PermissionFlag.Read, PermissionFlag.Write) => println("ok")
  case f                                                => println("ups")
}
```

which [works in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/bRde5MsnTaGCXDOEqwUMSw/9).

It would have all the benefits for enumerating possible flags, but not identify flag with a set of flags which is a great way of ending up in hairy situations.

Comment: Option 1 will remove the `values` and `withName` methods since they are not values

Comment: I'm using patten matching, values and withName also, like a regular enum

Comment: `enum` assumes that not only set of values is finite, but also every value in `values` is represented as a separate instance in runtime, that has to be instantiated upfront - if you want to represent binary flags that would require existence of 2^(number of flags)  possible values. IMHO this makes enum NOT a good use case for a `BitSet` alternative.

Comment: More sustainable approach was if  `Permission` was representation of a _single distinct flag_ which hold an ofset, and `Permissions` was representation of a `BitSet` where name is at first mapped to underlying Long and then checked in BitSet. Otherwise you would have to encode absurdities like: `NoPermission`, `Write`, `Read`, `WriteAndRead` as separate entities. It hardly scale for 2-3 values, doesn't scale at all for 4 and more.

Comment: For something like `permission match { case (Permission.Read | Permission.Write) => ... }` generated pattern matching would no longer work and you'd have to implement your own `unapply` methods, not really the direction one would pursue when looking for simplicity.

Comment: Its enough to me with the basic, checkout the following gist i created - maybe its will give more context
https://gist.github.com/ZviMints/e0edaabb1df169233cdf746e26fb1257

Comment: I believe you fixed yourself on using enums in particular way even though they don't really solve your problem: type of distinct flags could be represented by enum, to generate withNames, ordinal and values. Collection of possible on/off flags is by definition powerset of set of flags. It would better be represented as wrapped Set/BitSet/Long but not necessarily an enum. Otherwise hairy corner cases are about to pop up everywhere (e.g. `(Read | Write) & Read` would have the same long underneath but wouldn't pattern match to the same instance).

Comment: Just finished to read the anwer you supplied and its awesome usuage of opaque! unfortunately our main app is scala 2, is it possible to transform the answer / provide another answer with scala 2? that's great!

Comment: There is [Monix Newtypes](https://newtypes.monix.io/) which can be cross compiled between Scala 2 and 3 and does basically what I did. You can also just use `type Impl` without implementation and `wrap` and `unwrap` through `asInstanceOf`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the wanted behaviour using types and semigroups. Here is a solution in Scala 3 (you can make it Scala 2 by replacing extensions with implicit classes):

```
object Flags:
    opaque type FlaggedEnum = Long

    opaque type Permissions = FlaggedEnum

    object Permissions:
        val Write: Permissions = (1 << 0)
        val Read : Permissions = (1 << 1)

    trait Semigroup[A]:
        extension (source: A)
            def |(target: A): A
            def &(target: A): A
            def hasFlag(flag: A): Boolean

    private val semigroupFlaggedEnum = new Semigroup[FlaggedEnum]:
        extension (source: FlaggedEnum)
            def |(target: FlaggedEnum): FlaggedEnum = source | target
            def &(target: FlaggedEnum): FlaggedEnum = source & target
            def hasFlag(flag: FlaggedEnum): Boolean = (source & flag) != 0

    given Semigroup[Permissions] = semigroupFlaggedEnum

@main def main(): Unit =
    import Flags.*

    val w = Permissions.Write
    val r = Permissions.Read
    val perm = w | r
    println(perm)
```

**Note**: to add more `FlaggedEnum`s like `Permission`, simply add a new type like:

```
opaque type NewType = FlaggedEnum
```

and then add a given instance for this new type:

```
given Semigroup[NewType ] = semigroupFlaggedEnum
```

Comment: Since it has 2 binary operators it is at least Ring rather that Semigroup - in group theory algebras up to group deals with single binary operation, 2 binary operations group belong to ring theory.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok yes you're right, my terminology is wrong in this example